# Using Python API on Multi-Arch Linux

Tags: python, 64-bit, debian, x86-64

I have a code which uses Python API which I'm going to compile on a Debian Wheezy 64 bit operating system and get following error in compile time:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:873:2: error: #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
```

I've done a search but couldn't find out how should I use 32 bit packages. I've also installed `ia32-libs` and `g++-multilib` on my Wheezy still having this stupid error.

I've also opened `pyport.h` and found the error line:

```
#if LONG_BIT != 8 * SIZEOF_LONG
/* 04-Oct-2000 LONG_BIT is apparently (mis)defined as 64 on some recent
 * 32-bit platforms using gcc.  We try to catch that here at compile-time
 * rather than waiting for integer multiplication to trigger bogus
 * overflows.
 */
#error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
#endif
```

From other threads I got that on a multi-arch system there should be a folder like this:
    /usr/include/

Thanks in advance